# Setting permission on Raspberry Pi server

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi

Basically I set up my own raspberry pi web server. However, I'm having issues giving a website I wanna test the permission to run on the server...any idea what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use Apache2 or Nginx on your Raspberry Pi Server?

If using Apache2 you should add/edit files in sites-available directory.

Comment: I'm using Apache2, when I put the files in there my FTP client keeps coming back with "critical file transfer error"

Comment: You don't put web files into this dir. You create there config file to access web files folders. Look at [link](http://web.onassar.com/blog/2012/07/19/enabling-an-apache-virtual-host-with-sites-available-enabled-directory/) how to config it. In this file you paste path to your web folder.